# Adding a DPDT switch into schematic

Tags: kicad, toggle-switch

I'm learning to use Kicad and got stuck trying to add a DPDT switch to my schematic. When I try to add it, I couldn't find one in the components library when I search for it. How can I add it to my schematic on Kicad?

Comment: cant you search for libraries https://github.com/KiCad/Buttons_Switches_THT.pretty

Comment: Create one for yourself. It would only take a couple of minutes with the Pulsonix software I use.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, @Khi. No need to add "Solved" to your title. If you accept the answer that helps the best - even if you write it yourself - it shows up as answered on the home page.

Answer (score 2):

Switches like this are in the switches library.

You can add the library by selecting "Component Libraries" from the Preferences Menu, then selecting add.

On Linux the standard libraries are in /usr/share/kicad/library

If you're on another OS, the relevant directory is probably somewhere in the Current Search Path List in the original Component Libraries dialogue box described above. I'm sure a search for *.lib will make the appropriate library obvious if you're not running Linux.

The kicad forum is excellent by the way.